# ios : create NavigationBar programmatically, but cannot set the title

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, uinavigationbar

I create an NavigationBar programmaticlly without using xib file.
And create one left button with text "left", added to the navigationBar, and set the title to "Demo".

code :

```
-(void) createNavBar:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
{

    self.navBarController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
    navBar = [navBarController navigationBar];
    navBarController.navigationBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, navBarHeight);
    [navBarController.navigationBar  setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"www/images/ios_hd_bg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 2, 0)]
     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



    [navBarController view];

    navBarController.navigationItem.title = @"title";

    [navBarController.view setFrame:navBarController.navigationBar.bounds];

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button = [self renderNavBarTextBtn:@"left" withButton:button direction:@"left"];
    [navBar addSubview:button];

    [[[self webView] superview] addSubview: navBarController.view];
}
```

however, the program can successfully set the navigationbar background image, show the left button, but cannot set the title.  so strange?

complements:
I use cordova framework to invoke . and The inteface just be provided to cordova invoke.
Thanks for answers below, but I still can't solve my problem.

ScreenShot: (Note: showing the left button but not showing the title)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding back button to navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846539/adding-back-button-to-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 4):

```
 UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"left" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;

    self.navigationItem.title=@"Demo";
    [_backButton release], 
    [_backButton = nil];
```

Comment: I use cordova framework to invoke . and The inteface just be provided to cordova invoke. Thanks for answers below, but I still can't solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply u try this one  http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/05/navigation-bar-with-nativecontrols-in-cordova/

Comment: thanks for you kind. yes, I use the NativeControls plugin, but I modify something. I init the view programmatically, with the code "self.navBarController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];", and can not set the title.

Comment: I give this code for knowing the xcode concept. Actually i not knowing about this plugin than also i helped you. I need time for studying about this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Your Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
navBar.title =@"Your title";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your view title, which show title on navigation bar

```
self.title=@"My Navigation View";
```

Or you can set navigationBarTitle in the view where you want to show

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"My Navigation";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet :

```
//nativeControls.hideLeftNavButton();

    nativeControls.setupRightNavButton(
        "About",
        "",
        "onRightNavButton"
    );

    nativeControls.showNavBar();
```

otherwise refer to this blog : 
http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/05/navigation-bar-with-nativecontrols-in-cordova/